# Prevent a node module from being recreated or overwritten?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

Is there any way in node.js by which I can prevent a module to never be updated or overwritten?

Comment: Are you talking about `node_modules`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write it as exact version on dependencies property, for example:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "async": "1.3", // exact version this never will be changed/overwritten/updated/etc...
    "body-parser": "~1.5.2", // This could be updated to version reasonably close to 1.5.2
    "bower": "^1.3.8", // This could be updated to version compatible with 1.3.8
  }
```

[Please look at here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies) for the complete list of options.